# Consultar registros duplicados en tabla MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una base de datos en la cual el campo "productosCarrito" tiene datos como los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es de que al realizar la siguiente consulta no me devuelve nada:

```
SELECT `productosCarrito`, COUNT(*) Total
FROM `comprasrealizadasweb`
GROUP BY `productosCarrito`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Imagino que tiene que ver mucho el hecho de que haya dentro varios códigos de mis productos, espero que me puedan ayudar lo necesito.

Comment: Si no te devuelve nada, es que no hay ningún registro duplicado

Comment: Claro que lo hay @Japv, si observas bien el código 003-612 se repite

Comment: Si pero espera, tu tienes en un mismo campo varios códigos separados por espacio?

Comment: Exacto @Japv, hay manera de arreglarlo

Comment: Pues que lo tengas así no es correcto, deberías tener un código por fila

Comment: si, hay formas de hacer una consulta que devuelva el resultado que quieres